# How to track the events like rating, submit or cancel button of Google In-App review Android

Tags: android, in-app

I have successfully implemented In-App review in the app, it is working fine. My question is how can I trigger firebase analytics or moengage event analytics of Google In-App review dialog like rating(how many stars user has given), submit and cancel button of In-App dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get some info from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java#request-review-info). Where you can see such code:

```
ReviewManager manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this);
Task<ReviewInfo> request = manager.requestReviewFlow();
request.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        // We can get the ReviewInfo object
        ReviewInfo reviewInfo = task.getResult();
    } else {
        // There was some problem, continue regardless of the result.
    }
});
```

so you can call this scope. You can also read about handling reviewing process [here](https://proandroiddev.com/google-play-in-app-review-api-integration-and-experience-a96b30805345).

Comment: This i have implemented successfully. But i need to know how many stars(rating) the user has given to the app and track the submit and close button events via firebase analytics or moengage event analytics.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it will be possible, I will look for some more info for you also)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot track rating events
As you can see in docs:

> The API does not indicate whether the user reviewed or not, or even
> whether the review dialog was shown. Thus, no matter the result, we
> continue our app flow.

Google do not want to let you buy positive reviews for some gifts in your app.

You can implement your custom rating dialog and send user to store where he must score your app again